# Indicate level with Replace

Tags: replacement, syntax, rule

```
Replace[{{x^2, Sqrt[x]}, {x + 1, x - 3}}, f_[x__] -> f, 1]
```

Level 1 of Replace works here as expected with output {List,List}

```
Replace[{{x^2, Sqrt[x]}, {x + 1, x - 3}}, f_[x__] -> f, 2]
```

But with level 2 I would expect something like {{Power,Power},{Plus,Plus}}. However, the output still is {List,List}. Why?

Comment: Use {2} instead of 2.

Comment: @CarlWoll Oops, thanks! ;-)

Comment: @Gambit I have marked this question as *already has an answer* with links pointing to two older questions.  I believe you will find these informative.  If you still have questions let me know.